# When subclassing QAbstractItemModel, nothing shown in QTreeView

Tags: qt, qabstractitemmodel, qstandarditemmodel

I am trying to use [simple tree model](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/itemviews-simpletreemodel.html), but I am not able to make the example works in my project.

First, I was able to use QTreeView without problem, with QStandardItemModel.  In the following case, I am able to see my QTreeView with data inside.  See the working code :

```
constructor{
m_pModel = new QStandardItemModel();
ui.treeViewDevicesList->setModel(m_pModel);
fillTreeView(devicesList);
}

void GatewayDeviceViewerEditor::fillTreeView(const std::vector<Payload> &devicesList)
{
    QVector<QStandardItem *> parents(MAX_PARENTS);
    parents[0] = m_pModel->invisibleRootItem();

    for (vector<Payload>::const_iterator it = devicesList.begin() ; it != devicesList.end(); ++it)
    {
        QStandardItem *pTreeViewItem = new QStandardItem();
        string rootTitle =  it->deviceId + " " + it->deviceName + " " + it->status ;
        pTreeViewItem->setText(rootTitle.c_str());
        parents[0]->appendRow(pTreeViewItem);
       // parents[1] = pTreeViewItem;
    }
}
```

Now, the following code is NOT working.  I am trying to subclass the model.  In that case, the QTreeView is showing up but completly empty.  There is something that I guess that I don't understand.

```
entryPoint{
DeviceTreeModel deviceTreeModel(devicesList);
ui.treeViewDevicesList->setModel(&deviceTreeModel);
}

DeviceTreeModel::DeviceTreeModel(const std::vector<Payload> &devicesList, QObject *parent)
    : QAbstractItemModel(parent)
{
    QList<QVariant> rootData;
    rootData << "Title" << "Summary";
    m_pRootItem = new DeviceTreeItem(rootData);
    setupModelData(devicesList, m_pRootItem);
}

void DeviceTreeModel::setupModelData(const std::vector<Payload> &devicesList, DeviceTreeItem *parent)
{
    QList<DeviceTreeItem*> parents;
    parents << parent;


    for (vector<Payload>::const_iterator it = devicesList.begin() ; it != devicesList.end(); ++it)
    {
        string rootTitle =  it->deviceId + " " + it->deviceName + " " + it->status ;
        QString test(rootTitle.c_str());
        QList<QVariant> columnData;
        columnData << test << "Summary";

        parents.last()->appendChild(new DeviceTreeItem(columnData, parents.last()));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `entryPoint`, I think that the `deviceTreeModel` needs to be allocated with `new`, instead of being a local instance that will be destroyed when exiting the function.